# Autocorrelation of multiple time series in Matlab using FFT

Tags: matlab, time-series, fft, correlation

The Matlab function `autocorr` (documentation [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/econ/autocorr.html)) calculates the sample autocorrelation of a single time series using the fast fourier transform (FFT) algorithm:

```
nFFT = 2^(nextpow2(length(y))+1);
F = fft(y-mean(y),nFFT);
F = F.*conj(F);
acf = ifft(F);
acf = acf(1:(numLags+1)); % Retain non-negative lags
acf = acf./acf(1); % Normalize
acf = real(acf);
```

Suppose I have multiple realisations of the same stochastic process (time series) and I would like to calculate the sample autocorrelation. A naive approach would be to call `autocorr` for each time series and average the correlation at each lag. However it is better to consider all pairs of points seperated by lag k simultaneously. I have implemented this by building a `(n-iLag)*nSamples` by 2 matrix of all the pairs separated by lag-size `iLag` then calculating the sample correlation.

```
% input: samplesMat (nSamples (times series) by n (time points) matrix)

sizeMat = size(samplesMat);
nSamples = sizeMat(1); 
n = sizeMat(2);

ACF = zeros(n,1);

muHat = mean(mean(samplesMat)); % sample mean

for iLag = 0:(n-1)
    index = 1;
    nPairs = (n-iLag)*nSamples;
    pairs = zeros(nPairs,2);
    for iSample = 1:nSamples
        for ix = 1:(n-iLag)
            pairs(index,1) = samplesMat(iSample,ix);
            pairs(index,2) = samplesMat(iSample,ix+iLag);
            index = index + 1;
        end
    end

    X2 = pairs(:,1)-muHat;
    Y2 = pairs(:,2)-muHat;
    ACF(iLag+1) = sum(X2.*Y2)/n*nSamples % calculate covariance
end
ACF = ACF/ACF(1); % divide by variance
```

For a single time series `nSamples = 1` this code gives the same output as the `autocorr` despite being significantly slower. Is there a way to make use of the FFT algorithm to calculate the ACF for multiple time series?

Comment: Can’t you just concatenate the multiple realizations, and let `autocorr` do the averaging inside?

Comment: @AhmedFasih any kind of concatenation or taking the mean correlation does not give the same results as calculating the correlation for the pair matrix containing all pairs seperated by lag k. It is closeish but not the same value. The correlation between two vectors is not the same as subdividing those vectors calculating the correlation for each subdivision and averaging.

Comment: I suggested this just going on the definition of autocorrelation: the correlation between a sample of a (zero-mean unit-variance) random process and its value `i` samples back is `E[x(t) * x(t+i)]`. I was thinking, whether you have one or ten realizations of the process, this definition wouldn’t change.'

Comment: There are a number of corrections one has to apply (see [`autocorr` doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/autocorr.html#btzjcln-4) and [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Statistics)). You need to subtract the sample mean inside the expectation, choose the denominator for normalizing the sum to the mean, etc. I expect the differences you find between these methods come from not matching these bookkeeping steps?

Comment: @egg I am curious as to in which situation you required multiple time series, and whether you have a reference for the new sample covariance that you are estimating?

Comment: @Greenparker I was fitting a statistical model to timber where each tree could be considered an independent realisation of the same statistical process.

Comment: @egg Ah ok, thanks!. Any paper for reference for this?

Comment: @Greenparker no paper references sorry. I did figure out how to do it with FFT so I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

The same result is given by taking the arithmetic mean in the Fourier domain

```
function [ acf ] = corrFFT(samplesMat,denomType,mu)
% Adaptation of inbuilt function autocorr to allow for multiple
% realisations, known mean and variable denominator.
%
% Input:
% samplesMat - nx by nSamples matrix of realisations
% denomType (optional) - 'cnst' or 'var'
% mu (optional) - if true mean is known

if nargin < 2
    denomType = 'cnst';
end
if nargin < 3
    mu = mean(mean(samplesMat));
end

[nx,~] = size(samplesMat);

nFFT = 2^(nextpow2(nx)+1);
F = fft(samplesMat-mu,nFFT);
F = F.*conj(F);
acf = ifft(mean(F,2));
acf = acf(1:nx);
if strcmp(denomType,'var')
    acf = (nx./[nx:-1:1]').*acf;
end

acf = acf./acf(1);
acf = real(acf);
end
```